# How do I implement DNN Authentication from external desktop application?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I need a way to authenticate users to a DNN site from an external desktop application, in my case a OS X MAC Application.

The Desktop app needs access to Web API service methods on the DNN Site.  I think the JSON Web Token (JWT) would work for this, however, we are using DNN 7 and are unable to upgrade at this time. Is there another option to authenticate from outside of the framework? There does not appear to be a DNN API call to even check if a username and password are valid, as everything is strongly tied into .NET Identity. Is there a way to do this?

I want users to login to DNN directly from within a desktop app on MAC.

Answer (score 0):

You could use basic auth with SSL.  Here is an answer I gave on how to implement by authorizing web services with basic auth restricted by role.

[Basic auth in DNN Web API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028517/basic-auth-in-dnn-web-api-service/34052093#34052093)